# Add custom background to div in home page

Tags: theme-customizer, custom-background

I want to have featured image on specific `div` on home page that could be changed in customizer. I saw in documentation custom background for `body`(https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds) But I want to make it for specific div eg. `#featured-home-image`. How?

```
$args = array(
    'default-color' => '000000',
    'default-image' => '%1$s/images/background.jpg',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `wp-head-callback` argument to specify your own handler:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
    'wp-head-callback' => 'wpse_189361_custom_background_cb',
    'default-color'    => '000000',
    'default-image'    => '%1$s/images/background.jpg',
));

function wpse_189361_custom_background_cb() {
    ob_start();

    _custom_background_cb(); // Default handler

    $style = ob_get_clean();
    $style = str_replace( 'body.custom-background', '#featured-home-image', $style );

    echo $style;
}
```