# Add custom background to section in home page

Tags: custom-background

To be clear : in Wordpress there is an option to change the **body** backgroung-image. I want to modify this option to permit to change the background-image of a particular **section** (named #section1) and not the background-image of the body.

I know that this question has already been asked by Emir Dupovac, but I applied the advices given by TheDeadMedic and it just doesn't work...

[Link to the similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189361/add-custom-background-to-div-in-home-page)

In the file `functions.php` I made 3 changes :

1. I commented the part of the default code relating to the display of the background-image

   ```
   function espace_harmonie_body_classes( $classes ) {
   // Adds a class of custom-background-image to sites with a custom background image.
   /*if ( get_background_image() ) {
   $classes[] = 'custom-background-image';
   }*/
   ...
   }
   ```
2. I put this code in my `<template_name>_setup()` function :

   ```
   // Image in section  
   $defaults = array(
       'default-color'    => 'ff0000',
       'default-image'    => '%1$s/images/image-section.jpg',
       'default-repeat'         => '',
       'default-position-x'     => '',
       'default-attachment'     => '',
       'wp-head-callback' => 'wpse_189361_custom_background_cb',
       'admin-head-callback'    => '',
       'admin-preview-callback' => ''
   );
   add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $default);
   ```
3. And this one just after the `<template_name>_setup()` function :

   ```
   function wpse_189361_custom_background_cb() {
       ob_start();
       _custom_background_cb(); // Default handler
       $style = ob_get_clean();
       $style = str_replace( 'body.custom-background', '#section1', $style );
       echo $style;
   }
   ```

Despite these modifications, when I try to add a background image in the admin interface, the background is applied to the body and not to my section. Could someone explain me why? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the resulting $style?

Comment: Why not use CSS's `background-image` property on the section in question?

Comment: What's the current output from the custom background callback? PS: Please link to the mentioned question and it's solution and use the code format instead of using screenshots for the code, thanks

Comment: jgraup : How can I have the result of $style?

Comment: belinus : I want the background-image coulb be modified/customized through the wordpress amin interface. If I directly put my background-omage in the CSS I will not be able to do that.

Comment: birgire : How can I check the output? I update the question right now.

Comment: View the HTML source for the page and skim through it to locate the custom background style part. Please add that output to your question, thanks @HéloïseChauvel

Comment: @birgire :
Thanks I found it.
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-image: url('http://localhost/espace_harmonie/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/images.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: top left; background-attachment: scroll; }
</style>


Seems that it doesn't take my changes into account. That is what the default code should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! Finally I have found the solution! (even if I don't understand why we have to do this that way).

In fact we have not to modify the `function.php` file but the `customizer.php` with the code I quoted above (in the question).

Now I really feel released from that issue, but anyone could explain me why is it that file that we have to modify? I think I haven't really understood the role of the differents files.

*The inc subdirectory*

[image]

*The inc subdirectory content*

[image]

Comment: It should be `functions.php` in the current theme directory, not `function.php`. I'm not sure where the `customizer.php` file is located that you've edited.

Comment: Sorry this is a lack of precision, I first edited `functions.php` with a 'S', and this file is in my directory. `customizer.php` is in a subdirectory named `inc`.

Comment: Probably, if you look inside `functions.php` you will find that `customizer.php` is included there, if the user is an admin. By placing this block of customizer related functions in a different file, developers prevent it being loaded every time, also for ordinary users.

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you @cjbj for the specifications. Here are the related functions calling the files in the inc directory:
`/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';`